# Float awkward situation

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 3 `div` elements on a page with the float attribute set to left.

I add another `div` element without any styles but it's arranged like the ones I told you about above. Why ? I can't understand this.

Thank you

CODE:

```
  <div style="float:left">
   test first
  </div>

 <div style="float:left">
  test second
 </div>


 <div style="float:left">
   test third
 </div>

 <div>
  test fourth
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the related code in your question?

Comment: Can't help without seeing the code.

Comment: I've added the code. Sry

Comment: What's the problem? Three divs are floated to the left of one div.

Comment: I'm not very good with CSS. You are basically saying that 3 divs are floated to left relatively to the fourth one, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last div needs to clear the floats.

#### HTML

```
<div class="left">text</div>
<div class="left">text</div>
<div class="left">text</div>

<div class="clear-left">text</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.left { float: left; }
.clear-left { clear: left; }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4DWPD/)**